# Слово використувається чи вживається?

Tags: вибір-слова, стилістика

[Тут](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=m3p0DQAAQBAJ&pg=PT82&lpg=PT82&dq=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=lHd8B8Uh0H&sig=5a9LWRZUPzN5qEpqzGKyFA0F_T4&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWgNKo_rzbAhXLFSwKHbpOABYQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&f=false) знаходжу конструкцію "**використовувати слова**".

А [тут](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/leksika/vzhivannja_sliv_vidpovidno_do_jikhnogo_znachennja/5-1-0-51): **Слово має вживатися**.

Отже, як все ж більш коректно говорити: "я використовую слова" чи "я вживаю слова"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У  [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) знаходимо:

> Близькими [синонімами](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) поняття застосування є слова використання та вжиток. Обидва слова по суті означають той самий процес, але надають трохи інший відтінок, присмак. Використання зазвичай вживається там, де треба підсилити значення користі, корисних наслідків для ініціатора застосування. Слово вжиток, навпаки, дещо затьмарює ціль, в тих випадках коли йдеться про звичне буденне застосування.

Отже, нормативно говорити і **вживаю** слово і **використовую**.